# How to rectify junit giving assertion error as expected:1 and actual:0?

Tags: java, junit

I have a junit method like this :

```
    public void testMyStuff() {
        IMockBuilder<BackingBean> builder = createMockBuilder(BackingBean.class);
        builder.addMockedMethod("getMyFacesContextSessionMap");
        BackingBean bean = builder.createMock();
        MyVO MyVO = new MyVO();
        List<MyVO> MyVOList = new ArrayList<MyVO>();
        HttpServletRequest req = createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        bean.setHttpServletRequest(req);
        MyVOList.add(buildMyVO());
        expect(bean.getMyFacesContextSessionMap()).andReturn(
                new HashMap<String, Object>());
        expect(ac.getBean("MyService")).andReturn(service);
        expect(MyFacade.getMyStuff(MyVO)).andReturn(MyVOList);
        expect(bean.getMyFacesContextSessionMap()).andReturn(
                new HashMap<String, Object>());
        replay(bean, MyFacade);
        bean.setService(service);
        String returnString = bean.myStuff();
        assertEquals("myNo", returnString);
    }
```

When i run it as junit in eclipse i get this error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Unexpected method call MyFacadeLocal.getMyStuff(MyVO@8c64cdd8):
    MyFacadeLocal.getMyStuff(MyVO@d79a467f): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at $Proxy1.getMyStuff(Unknown Source)
```

I am not understanding how to rectify this . Can some one help me plz ?

Comment: What is `MyVO` class? (For clarity, you should name the variable `myVO`)

Comment: @Samy The MyVO is a simple POJO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of an ArgumentMatcher:

```
public class CollectionCountMatcher implements IArgumentMatcher
{
    private int expectedCount;

    public CollectionCountMatcher(int count) {
        super();
        this.expectedCount = count;
    }

    public boolean matches(Object actual) {
         return (actual instanceof Collection) 
         && ((Collection) actual).size() == expectedCount;
    }

    public static final Integer eqObject(Integer inValue) {
        EasyMock.reportMatcher(new CollectionCountMatcher (inValue));
        return inValue;
    }

    public void appendTo(StringBuffer buffer) {
        buffer.append("collectionContains(" + expectedCount + ")");
    }
}
```

You create an MyVOMatcher and you call your mock method like this:

```
expect(MyFacade.getMyStuff(MyVOMatcher.eqObject(MyVO))).andReturn(MyVOList);
```

EDIT: Or what you can also do, but this way of working is less strict and doesn't check for different objects is doing it like this:

```
expect(MyFacade.getMyStuff(EasyMock.anyObject(myVO.class))).andReturn(MyVOList);
```

This will work for sure, but off course you can pass every possible argument, as long as it's of the type MyVO

Comment: Thanks for the code, i will try to use that and get back to you in case it helps.

Comment: Excuse me, I made a mistake in my last code sample. It should be like this: expect(MyFacade.getMyStuff(EasyMock.anyObject(myVO.class))).andReturn(MyVOList);

Comment: I tried this one out as you suggested : `expect(((IExpectationSetters<Object>) MyFacade.getMyStuff(EasyMock.anyObject(myVO.class))).andReturn(MyVOList));`

The problem is it gives me NPE like : ` java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TestMystuff.testMyStuff(TestMystuff.java:369)` . Really can't figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: What's exactly causing your NPE? that exact line?

Comment: This line : `expect(((IExpectationSetters<Object>) MyFacade.getMyStuff(EasyMock.anyObject(myVO.class))).andReturn(MyVOList));`

Comment: Ahh, my bad..  I had a bracket problem here .. Thats why the NPE. But now its giving another error .I will try to solve that. Thanks for helping me . Accepted .

Answer (score 0):

This means that the method

```
getMyStuff
```

with as argument MyVO is never called in your backing bean. Check if that method is really called. If that's the case, implement the equals() and hashCode() methods for MyVO since probably it's not recognized as the same element since it's a different object.

The error message just tells you you expect the method with the EXACT parameter that you specify, but that it wasn't encountered...

Comment: How do i implement the equals() method ? I had tried something like :
`@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  
  if ((obj instanceof MyVO)) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }`
But that did not work.. I got the same error again .

Comment: The code that you have here , is exactly the same as what i have given.  What's the diff ? Can you elaborate ??

Comment: Try also to override your hashCode() method. Can't you debug inside the service you call? You can put your breakpoint on the line where MyFacadeLocal.getMyStuff(MyVO@d79a467f) is called... If the object that is passed as a parameter is not the same object but is 'equal' to the object you pass, you can create a Matcher class that implements  the IArgumentMatcher of EasyMock

Comment: I have debugged the service call and i know the problem is that i have here same object of different instances. The question is , how do i then implement an equals method to get rid of this problem ? Do you have any sample links or urls where   such a thing has been done? Then it will become easier for me to replicate it. Otherwise i am at a loss here.

Comment: I elaborated an example in a different answer and proposed a workaround to fix your test...

Comment: Thanks , lemme have a look at that .

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because getMyStuff is a static method. Mocking static methods is not ideal with EasyMock. Maybe consider Powermock and if you want to do it in EasyMock anyway, you can try the following:

You could move the static call to a method, override this method in the instantiation of the tested class in the test class, create a local interface in the test class and use its method in the overidden method:

```
private interface IMocker 
{
    List<MyVO> getMyStuff(MyVO myVO);
}

IMocker imocker = EasyMock.createMock(MyFacade.class);

...

@Override
List<MyVO> getMyStuff(MyVO myVO)
{
    imocker.getMyStuff(myVO);
}

...

EasyMock.expect(imocker.getMyStuff(EasyMock.anyObject(myVO.class))).andReturn(true);
```